# Converting from a String(number) to Integer to Binary-Form (String)

Tags: java

I'm making a program that imitates the tabulation method (Quine McCluskey) and I'm trying to convert the input in **String** format to **Integer** format and finally back to **String** (in Binary form) format.

I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: 
>       ""
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

and here's the line with the error:

```
String a = toBinary(Integer.parseInt(a1));
```

any tips on how should I better approach this conversion? Assuming that the input is correct (only numbers are on the String).

EDIT: I forgot to include this method..

```
public String toBinary(Integer input) {
    String binString = Integer.toBinaryString(input);

    while(binString.length()<8) //for PADDING zeroes up front
        binString = "0" + binString;    

    System.out.println("\nBinString: " + binString);
    return binString;
}
```

Comment: It is always important to read the stacktrace. It says the exception happens in `java.lang.Integer.parseInt`, thus the issue is not in `toBinary`, but rather with `a1` which contains an empty String. You need to find our why.

Comment: Yes. I just included it for clarification. Some might say that the "to binary" string is ".toBinaryString". Also, I passed a value to a1 by these line:

String var1 = elementBinValue(mainRec.get(i));
String var2 = elementBinValue(mainRec.get(k));
if(compareTo(var1, var2)==1

I don't want to include "elementBinValue" method since I already checked and it works fine and even returned the string I needed before passing it to "compareTo" method.

Comment: The stacktrace doesn't lie. Although you removed the line of the stacktrace where it mentions your own code, it is the first starting point. Find that line and find out what you really passes to `java.lang.Integer.parseInt(..)`. You need to debug that, but Stackoverflow can't help you to debug your code.

Comment: Okay thanks. Just in case, this code `String a = toBinary(Integer.parseInt(a1));` works, right?

Comment: Again, your stacktrace looks like `a1` is the culprit, thus this line is generally fine, but during runtime `a1` contains something you or your program doesn't expect. When you use `toBinary(Integer.parseInt("1234"));` instead, when everything would work without an exception. If it does, then you need to debug the source of `a1`s value and why it assigns an empty String. Maybe that code itself receives a value it doesn't expect and the empty String is just the initial/fallback value?

Comment: Thanks for telling me. I rechecked everything and found out my "checker" to check the results of the code is off. **a1 indeed does not have a value**. Thank you so much sir Tom

Comment: You're welcome. If you think this question has a value for future readers with a similar issue, then feel free to post an answer to your own question, so these readers understand how to fix such issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the code was fine. The main reason for the error was **a1** which is returning nothing. Got errors on previous methods. Thanks

```
String a = toBinary(Integer.parseInt(a1));
```

a1 is a String type and it should not be empty in this line.